# Не cрабатывает scrollTop jqery

Tags: jquery

У меня почему то не работает scrolTop.Буду рад любой помощи!

```js
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#contacts").scrollTop(600);
   
   });
```

```css
  .cont{
        width: 200px;
        height: 1500px;
        border: solid red 1px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

 
</head>

<body>
    <button>Кнопка</button>
    <div class="cont"></div>
    <div class="c" id="contacts">Контакты</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не работает *scrollTop* потому, что он применяется у Вас к `#contacts`, который пустой и в нём нечего прокручивать. В данном случае, Вам нужно прокрутить `document`:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(document).scrollTop(1500);
});
```

```css
.cont {
  width: 200px;
  height: 1500px;
  border: solid red 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Кнопка</button>
<div class="cont"></div>
<div class="c" id="contacts">Контакты</div>
```

Comment: Не пойдёт, у него высота просто для красоты написана, а так она будет разная от внутреннего контента. Надо было внутрь контента добавить, Lorem какойнить и уже нормально показать. Это я не придираюсь, просто совет переделать правильно)